# How to restrict data of different tabs on initial load of the web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

div#tabCtrl

div#page1 The below table displays the tab1 data

div#page2 The below table displays the tab2 data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the page content is within the tab element, you could set the tabs to display none by default, and the initial page load would set the default tab to display block. I have created a quick fiddle to demonstrate that:

https://jsfiddle.net/mnL97xtd/

```
<div id="tabCtrl"> <a href="#" onclick="activateTab('page1')">Tab 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="activateTab('page2')">Tab 2</a>

<div id="page1" class="tab" style="display:none">Tab 1 Content</div>
<div id="page2" class="tab" style="display:none">Tab 2 Content</div>
</div>
<script>
    activateTab("page1");
</script>



//inside a JS file
var activateTab = function (tab) {
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].style.display = (tabs[i].id === tab ? "block" : "none");
    }
}
```

Comment: My answer does.....unless you mean in the context of your current method? in which case I would need to actually see the HTML  before knowing where you function is having issues. Are you calling the activateTab function on first page load, or only when you click a tab? If you only call it when you click a tab, and the default display for your tabs are 'block', then that is where your problem is

Comment: actvateTab is called after pressing the link.Please find the whole code above.I am new to web dev plz help

Comment: Your original code doesn't appear to render correctly in the question, so I have tried to understand the layout as best as I can tyo create an example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aLxLdsfk/   This is what you already have, but with a script take after to set the initial active tab. Another thing, which isnt part of the answer but may be helpful for you, is that HTML 5 had introduced 'semantic' elements for header and nav elements: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp